# PHP XLS 2003 (Excel) File - Detecting Cell Vertical Alignment

Tags: php, excel

I need to make a slight change to the PHP Excel Reader library; http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

I want to add support for vertical-alignment of cells (top, middle, bottom).

Here's how the normal alignment is detected:

```
                    $alignbit = ord($data[$pos+10]) & 3;
```

And here is the excel 2003 format specification:

http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf

I'm not sure if this is the correct setting:

Does anyone know what bit I need to get (similar to the $alignbit) in order to get the vertical alignment? (1 of 6 possibilities)

[image]

[image]
Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use

```
$horizontalAlign = (0x07 & ord($data[$pos+10])) >> 0;
```

rather than

```
$horizontalAlign = ord($data[$pos+10]) & 3;
```

because you can then match the mask (0x07) up with the spec definition more obviously

Using the same principle, vertical alignment is bits 6-4, mask 0x70, so

```
$verticalAlign = (0x70 & ord($data[$pos+10])) >> 4;
switch ($verticalAlign) {
    case 0:
        //  VERTICAL_TOP
        break;
    case 1:
        //  VERTICAL_CENTER
        break;
    case 2:
        //  VERTICAL_BOTTOM
        break;
    case 3:
        //  VERTICAL_JUSTIFY
        break;
    case 4:
        //  VERTICAL_DISTRIBUTED
        break;
}
```

PS. Why are you still using Open Office's partial spec, when Microsoft have published the full specification

Comment: Excellent, thank you oh so very much. I had no idea there was an official spec of ms 2003? Thanks though.

Comment: You can find the full spec for .xls BIFF files at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154(v=office.12).aspx - an invaluable resource for the developer of PHPExcel